# VBS script to grab all images and add value to duplicates

Tags: file, vbscript, directory

I'm looking to grab all the files out of the E:\ drive without specifying a folder. I want the script to just grab all the files in the E: drive. Here is my script I have. I've tried multiple ways to write it, but am unsucessful on getting it to work. Here is my script thats working by grabbing the folder inside of the drive. The second one is the one I tried to modify to get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

testfolder = ".\allpictures"
'fso.CreateFolder(testfolder)

CopyFiles fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\virix\Desktop\mytest") 

Sub CopyFiles(fldr)
  For Each f In fldr.Files
    basename  = fso.GetBaseName(f)
    extension = fso.GetExtensionName(f)
    If LCase(extension) = "jpg" or LCase(extension) = "jpeg" Then
      dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder, f.Name)
      count = 0
      Do While fso.FileExists(dest)
        count = count + 1
        dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder, basename & "_" & count & "." _
          & extension)
      Loop
      f.Copy dest
    End If
  Next

  For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
    CopyFiles sf
  Next
End Sub
```

Here is the one I modified, but can't get to work.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

testfolder = ".\allpictures"
'fso.CreateFolder(testfolder)

StartCopy fso.GetDrive("E:\")

Sub StartCopy(fldr)
  For Each f In fldr.Files 
    basename  = fso.GetBaseName(f)
    extension = fso.GetExtensionName(f)
    If LCase(extension) = "jpeg" or LCase(extension) = "jpg" Then
      dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder, f.Name)
      count = 0
      Do While fso.FileExists(dest)
        count = count + 1
        dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder, basename & "_" & count & "." _
          & extension)
      Loop
      f.Copy dest
    End If
  Next

  For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
    StartCopy sf
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

testfolder = ".\allpictures"
'fso.CreateFolder(testfolder)

StartCopy fso.GetFolder("E:\")

Sub StartCopy(fldr)
  For Each Subfolder in fldr.SubFolders
  For Each f In fldr.Files 
    basename  = fso.GetBaseName(f)
    extension = fso.GetExtensionName(f)
    If LCase(extension) = "jpeg" or LCase(extension) = "jpg" Then
      dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder, f.Name)
      count = 0
      Do While fso.FileExists(dest)
        count = count + 1
        dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder, basename & "_" & count & "." _
          & extension)
      Loop
      f.Copy dest
    End If
  Next
   StartCopy Subfolder
  Next

  For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
    StartCopy sf
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: No that still did not work this has been giving me real problems lately and i'm puzzled on why it keeps breaking on me. E is an external drive i'm not sure if that would make a difference or not. I want to use this on my hard disks as well as my externals, but not sure why its breaking.

Comment: are you sure you have drive E ?

Comment: Yes I'm sure I just messed around with it a little bit. I tried drive C and it worked so im not sure why its not working on E it keeps saying path not found when I know its there, which is making me very confused on why its not finding it. I even went as far as listing my volumes on my hard drive just to make sure its showing up. I've tried writting it as E E: and E:\, but still not luck on getting it to work. E was an extra hard drive I had that I added and I know it works and it is visable. Its labeled as Backup(e:). I have no idea why its not working...

Comment: Ok after doing some testing on a few of my hard drives it works on every one, but this E. Any ideas why that would be and is there a way to possibly search the computer first to find all available drives to see if they are "true"?

Comment: Check type and value of `fldr` at the beginning of `StartCopy()`: `WScript.Echo TypeName(fldr) : WScript.Echo fldr`. Also check the permissions on drive `E:`.